# Populating a drop down list with data from the database

Tags: database, spring, forms, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm trying to populate a drop down list with data from the database, any help in the right direction would be appreciated

This is the form:

```
<div align="center">
    <form:form action="saveLid" method="post" modelAttribute="lid">
        <table border="0">
            <tr>
                <td>Street:</td>
                <td>
                    <form:select path="streetcode">
                        <form:option value="-1" label="kies een street" />
                        <form:options items="${listStreet}" />
                    </form:select>
                </td>
                <td><form:errors path="streetcode" cssClass="error" /></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td colspan="3" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Register" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
</div>
```

The controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveLid")
private ModelAndView listStreet() {
    List<Street> listStreet = lidDAO.listStreet();
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("saveLid");
    model.addObject("listStreet", listStreet);
    return model;
}
```

The DAOImpl:

```
@Override
```

public List listStreet() {
       String sql = "SELECT streetcode, ressort_id, ressort, streetnumber, streetname FROM Street";
        List listStreet = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new RowMapper() {

```
@Override
public Street mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
    Street str = new Street();
        str.setStreetcode(rs.getInt("streetcode"));
        str.setRessortId(rs.getInt("ressort_id"));
        str.setRessort(rs.getString("ressort"));
        str.setStreetname(rs.getString("streetname"));
            return str;
        }
    });
    return listStreet;
}

the model:

public class Street {
    public int streetcode;
        int ressortId;
        String ressort;
        public String streetname;

//getter and setters
}
```

Comment: Hi there! I formatted your HTML to appear, it was trying to be rendered as actual HTML code before because it wasn't fully formatted. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more help on formatting. Also it would be helpful if you edited your post to explain more about what you're trying to do, what you've tried so far and why you're having trouble. This info helps people write better answers.

Comment: Please elaborate your problem their is no description regarding problem faced.

Comment: The problem is that the drop down list in the view is not being populated.